# About taking the dual form of a boolean expression

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

If I take the dual form of a boolean expression and simplify it using some other theorems, after I'm done simplifying, do I need to take the dual of it again to obtain the original expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, you need to take the dual of it again.